# Bootstrap link styling to all text within div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

here is my code : 
UPDATE : jsfiddle hre : http://jsfiddle.net/vn0nwztg/3/

```
<a href="#" class="cancel_link_formating"><article class="article_container">
                <p class="article_tag2">Month Highlight</p>
                <img class="article_tag_country_flag" src="C:\Users\laurent\GoogleDrive\whichmeal\programing\Website building pinegrow_2\images\flags\flags\flags\32\Singapore.png">                        
                <img class="article_image_hompage" src="C:\Users\laurent\Google Drive\whichmeal\App content\content country\Singapore\pics\around_food\singapore_river_v2.jpg">     
                <h2 class="article_title_hompage">So Singapore !</h2>
                <p class="article_text_hompage">Singapore , officially the Republic of Singapore, is a sovereign city-state and island country in Southeast Asia. 
                It lies off the southern tip of the Malay Peninsula and is 137 kilometres (85 mi) north of the equator [...]</p>        
            </article></a>
```

As you can see, i had wrapped the whole "article" within a "a" attribute. 
Bootstrap somehow only applies its link styling  on the **last** "p" element. 
I managed to  **modify** the styling of this element  by adding the the  attrivbute a "cancel_link_formating" ... in an external stylesheet

Question is : i would like to apply the  same styling to the  "h2" attribute. How can I acheive this ?

my css :

```
.article_text_hompage{
font-size:16px;
padding:10px 0px 0px 0px;
width:90%;
display:block;
text-align:center;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
font-family: "Roboto Slab","cambria";
 }


a.cancel_link_formating{
color:#2C3646;
}

 a.cancel_link_formating:hover{
color:#A9A9A9;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of:

```
.article_title_hompage{
//this css color:
    color: #2C3646;
}
```